# Python request in AWS Lambda timing out

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to make a http request from my AWS Lambda but it times out.

My code looks similiar to this:

```
import requests

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print('Im making the request')
    request.get('http://www.google.com')
    print('I recieved the response')
```

But when I test this, I get a timeout.

The output is

```
Im making the request
END RequestId: id
REPORT RequestId: id    Duration: 15003.25 ms   Billed Duration: 15000 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 18 MB  
2016-04-08T20:33:49.951Z id Task timed out after 15.00 seconds
```

So I know the issue isn't it not finding the request package, and it's running my python code. I just figure out why it times out on that request.

Comment: Did you enable VPC access for your Lambda function?

Comment: Yep, VPC access enabled.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I encounter same [timeout problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42312496/aws-lambda-using-firebase-admin-initializeapp-timeout/42329809#42329809), the reason is below.

[AWS document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html):

> When you add VPC configuration to a Lambda function, it can only access resources in that VPC. If a Lambda function needs to access both VPC resources and the public Internet, the VPC needs to have a Network Address Translation (NAT) instance inside the VPC.

Maybe there are some error when you setting your VPC.
I advice you can follow this [blog](https://medium.com/@philippholly/aws-lambda-enable-outgoing-internet-access-within-vpc-8dd250e11e12#.bhx40hq3e) to build NAT.

Answer (score 20):

The default value for timeout in Lambda is 3 seconds = 3,000 milliseconds.
Go to Advanced settings and add 5 min.
This could be the only issue, if the timeout happens exactly at 3 seconds. All other errors would take something more or less than that.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for your help. You might want to make your answer even better by adding some explanation.

Comment: The steps are: In AWS Console go inside the Lambda function -> Click 'Configuration' tab -> click 'Edit' -> Set 'Timeout' to the necessary value.

Answer (score 9):

A Lambda function with VPC access will not have internet access unless you add a NAT gateway to your VPC. You should read the "Things to Know" section of the [Lambda VPC support announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-access-resources-in-a-vpc-from-your-lambda-functions/).

If you've enabled VPC support for your Lambda function, but don't have a NAT gateway in your VPC, then your request is timing out trying to access the internet.

Comment: Added a NAT Gateway to the VPC and a route for 0.0.0.0 through that NAT but still missing something. Timeouts still occur.

Comment: I wonder if the NAT is still required if a Public Subnet is specified?

Comment: Yes it is still required because the Lambda function doesn't get a public IP address.

Answer (score 5):

You can increase the timeout period for the request by doing the following:

```
response = requests.get(url, timeout=60)
```

Also, you will need to increase the timeout period for your lambda function. To do this:

- Open your lambda function in AWS
- Select 'Configuration', then 'Advanced Settings'
- Increase your time out period (up to 5 minutes)
- Select 'Save'

Also, I believe 'request.get' should be 'requests.get'.

Answer (score 1):

By default, AWS Lambda has 3 seconds of timeout so if your code is running for more than 3 seconds, it will automatically timeout giving you this error.

You can increase the timeout for your lambda function to up to 5 mins (300 seconds - AWS may increase this limit in the future) and that should take care of the problem.

Plus your code should reflect requests.get instead of request.get

Comment: where can you do this? couldn't find the place

Comment: The timeout is set in the lambda page for that function. If you scroll down, under Basic Settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. If you are running lambda outside of a VPC, make sure you are in a Region that supports SES. If the region doesn't support it the lambda functions are always going to fail.

Answer (score -1):

I have configured VPC configuration in **Lambda** function and also added the **NAT** gateway, set the function time to 5 minutes.

Still the problem `timed out after XX-- seconds` existed. By setting [context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html) to false solved the problem for me.

Comment: does this also exist for Python as the question is about Python