# AWS Lambda function boto3 queue issue

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda

I am having trouble getting the queue using boto3 in an AWS Lambda function.

If I type the code below and run directly then it is working. However, if I create the package and upload the zip file, it not working.

My sample code is as:

```
import boto3
import json

print('Loading function')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
sqs = boto3.resource('sqs', region_name='us-west-2', aws_access_key_id='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', aws_secret_access_key='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')

for queue in sqs.queues.all():
    print("===="+str(queue))

queue = sqs.get_queue_by_name(QueueName='testqueue')
print(" queue :: "+str(queue))
```

Why is it not working with package zip file?

Comment: I got the problem root cause of problem.
I selected the VPC in lambda function configuration, if i remove VPC than it's working.
How to solve this problem.

Comment: See my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36508974/python-request-in-aws-lambda-timing-out/36509205#36509205

Comment: Did you associate it to a Public Subnet, or a Private Subnet?

Comment: Hi John,

Thanks for response. I associated it to a Public Subnet.

If i make a simple http request getting the timeout.

headers   = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
        http = httplib2.Http(disable_ssl_certificate_validation=True)

        print "before http request"
        response, respData = http.request("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36508974/python-request-in-aws-lambda-timing-out/36509205#36509205", 'GET', headers=headers)
        print "response ",response, respData