# AWS Lambda using firebase-admin initializeApp timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, aws-lambda, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I use Lambda to Firebase message. I ref [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37325775/amazon-lambda-to-firebase). But the lambda function still timeout because it cannot connect to google server.

Handler.js

```
/ [START imports]
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require("../serviceAccount.json");

module.exports.message = (event, context, callback) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;  
  const registrationToken = "xxxxxxx";

  const payload = {
    data: {
      score: "850",
      time: "2:45"
    }
  };

  // [START initialize]
  if(firebase.apps.length == 0) {   // <---Important!!! In lambda, it will cause double initialization.
    firebase.initializeApp({
      credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
      databaseURL: 'https://messaging-xxxxx.firebaseio.com'
    });
  }

  // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
  // registration token.
  firebase.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationToken, payload)
    .then(function(response) {
      // See the MessagingDevicesResponse reference documentation for
      // the contents of response.
      console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
      callback(null, {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify("Successful!"),
      });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error sending message:", error);
      callback(null, {
        statusCode: 500,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          "status": "error",
          "message": error
        })
      })
    });
};
```

CloudWatch

> [Error: Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "connect ETIMEDOUT 172.217.26.45:443".]

But I use same serviceAccount.json to run on my ec2 and work find.
Does someone encounter this?

Comment: How have you added your `serviceAccount.json` file? I assume you uploaded a zip to Lambda and it's not just inline code?

Comment: Is this thread helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36508974/python-request-in-aws-lambda-timing-out

Comment: @Deif I use serverless to upload my serviceAccount.json file.

Comment: @jacobawenger Thank you the link. You give me right direction!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a couple hours struggling, I finally find the reason.
Because my Lambda using VPC to connect RDS and the network interface of VPC only have private IP.

[AWS document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html):

> When you add VPC configuration to a Lambda function, it can only access resources in that VPC. If a Lambda function needs to access both VPC resources and the public Internet, the VPC needs to have a Network Address Translation (NAT) instance inside the VPC.

So I need to create NAT inside the VPC.
I follow this [Blog](https://medium.com/@philippholly/aws-lambda-enable-outgoing-internet-access-within-vpc-8dd250e11e12#.bhx40hq3e) and problem solved.