# Lambda/nodejs http put timing out with no VPC set up

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, http, aws-lambda

I'm trying to do a HTTP PUT via node js in AWS lambda, but I keep getting time outs. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36508974/python-request-in-aws-lambda-timing-outvgx.png) "A Lambda function with VPC access will not have internet access unless you add a NAT", but in my case I'm not using a VPC.

```
exports.handler = (event, context) => {
      const options = {
          host: 'xxx',
          path: 'xxx',
          port: 443,
          method: 'PUT'
      };
    req = http.request(options, (res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
};
```

Comment: Could you please add full lambda function code?

Comment: @Grynets sure, just added.

Comment: You say you're doing a POST, but I see PUT in the code... could it be the reason?

Comment: @CaioDornellesAntune just fixed the text, I actually meant PUT.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with Lambda node.js. 
If you'd like to use node.js version 8, you should write code like this [example](http:///compute/node-js-8-10-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda/)

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  const options = {
      host: 'xxx',
      path: 'xxx',
      port: 443,
      method: 'PUT'
  };
  const response = await http.request(options);
  console.log(response);
};
```

If you don't want to use node.js version 8, you should add third parameter `callback` and call it after function execution.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const options = {
      host: 'xxx',
      path: 'xxx',
      port: 443,
      method: 'PUT'
  };
  req = http.request(options, (res) => {
    console.log(res);
    callback();
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The way your code is written, it is not returning anything as a response.

You can do it this way (using `callback` in `node` 4, 6 or 8) ...

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const options = {
        host: 'xxx',
        path: 'xxx',
        port: 443,
        method: 'PUT'
    };

    return http.request(options, (result) => {
        console.log(result);

        // Calling callback sends "result" to API Gateway.
        return callback(null, result);
    });
};
```

Or, if you want to use `node` 8's support for promises...

```
// You can use `async` if you use `await` inside the function.
// Otherwise, `async` is not needed. Just return the promise.
exports.handler = (event, context) => {
    const options = {
        host: 'xxx',
        path: 'xxx',
        port: 443,
        method: 'PUT'
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return http.request(options, result => {
            return resolve(result)
        })
    })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `req.end()` after the request.

```
const req = http.request(options)
req.end()
```