# Python) Any reference to call Rest API made by AWS gateway using AWS Lambda?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, api, rest, aws-lambda

Here, I have created DB REST API using API Gateway, method is POST. I want to build a another REST API that calls the DB API, which passes the event to DB API and return the response from it (with some more jobs). Both languages are Python 3.9

While I could use **requests** library from outside of AWS Lambda and call DB API and got the result, using the exact same code and run it at AWS Lambda gives me error message that it **cannot connect to DB API**.

I checked both DB API function and API caller function in same VPC, same security code and the role has following: [image: roles]

I know I can just invoke DB API lambda function inside the Lambda but I need that REST API so that other services can access to that DB API

Can anyone help me on achieving what I want? Thank you

**ADDED**

So I want to know what I have missed when people usually calls AWS gateway API by AWS lambda.

My expectation was since it worked in other environment, it must work at lambda too but in reality it wasn't even able to connect to the API.

I used the following code to call the API:

```
# DB API caller
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    URL = 'THE_URL_OF_DEPLOYED_API'
    timeout = 10

    # event is in format of dictionary
    response = requests.post(URL, json=event, timeout=timeout)
```

Comment: Sadly your question is not clear. You have to describe better what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Followed by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36509205/8752774). I found both my DB API and DB caller API lambda functions were in within same VPC. DB API function needs the VPC setting  BUT DB caller API actually didn't needed VPC. So I removed the VPC configuration from DB API caller lambda function and I could successfully got the response.